# Is normal the only rotation-invariant distribution whose marginals are normal?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

From Maxwell's theorem, standard normal distribution is the only rotation-invariant distribution with fully-factorized marginals. What if we do not ask the marginals to be independent, but instead require them to be univariate standard normal? Will multivariate standard Gaussian distribution still be the only rotation-invariant distribution?

Comment: Not sure if it is correct, this is just a guess: Since elliptical distributions have rotational symmetry, you may consider a random vector with univariate standard normal as marginals, and they are connected by a multivariate t copula. Not sure if this will meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this holds as a corollary to the Cramer-Wold theorem. The statement can be even stronger: Normal distribution is the only distribution whose marginals in all possible directions are normal.

Comment: Thanks to Klartag's CLT for convex bodies, a distribution which is isotropic and log-concave has this property in almost every direction.